# Can not get the value from Input React (react-rails gem)

Tags: reactjs

I am using React with `react-rails` gem.

```
var MeventShow = createReactClass({

getInitialState() {
 return {editable: false }
},

handleDelete(id) {
  this.props.handleDelete(id)
},

handleEdit() {
  var titler  = this._title.value;
  console.log('in handleEdit', this.state.editable, name);
  this.setState({editable: !this.state.editable})
},

render() {
var mevent = this.props.mevent
var title = this.state.editable ? <input type='text' id="inputShowTitle"     ref={(c) => this._title = c} defaultValue={mevent.title} /> : <h4 id="showTitle" onDoubleClick={this.handleEdit}>{mevent.title}</h4>
return (
  <div className="row">
    {title}
  </div>  
)
}
})
```

when I try to run `handleEdit()` , I get the error like `this._title is undefined`. It occurs in the first line of `handleEdit()`. If I use same code without condition part in `render` method, it works fine. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why you havent added event handle onChange to input?

Comment: As I said , I put the same code in my Form , it works without `onChange` , but  there is a condition in `render` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the value after `<input />` rendered(in setState callback), like this:

```
var MeventShow = createReactClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {editable: false }
  },

  handleDelete(id) {
    this.props.handleDelete(id)
  },

  handleEdit() {
    this.setState({editable: !this.state.editable}, () => {
      var titler  = this._title.value;
      console.log('in handleEdit', this.state.editable, name);
    })
  },

  render() {
    var mevent = this.props.mevent
    var title = this.state.editable ? <input type='text' id="inputShowTitle"     ref={(c) => this._title = c} defaultValue={mevent.title} /> : <h4 id="showTitle" onDoubleClick={this.handleEdit}>{mevent.title}</h4>
    return (
        <div className="row">
          {title}
        </div>
    )
  }
})
```